# Problem call WCF service from OOB (Out Of browser) application in Silverlight 3

Tags: wcf, silverlight-3.0

I'm very happy to new SL3, so i converted an application from SL2 to SL3. My application works fine on browser but i've some problem out of browser: the installer is ok but when i start the application out of browser i have the following problems:

1. the images in the ClientBin\Images is not show on the application (maybe only the xap is downloaded?)
2. i'm not able to call the WCF web services (exception), but i could from the browser.

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Could you post your exception

Comment: The complete exception, including all InnerExceptions. Catch the exception, then post the result of ex.ToString().

Answer (score 0):

Delete all your services generated from silver client and then add again!